# Как на Linux заставить OpenCV билдиться с FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, opencv, cmake, ffmpeg, build

Пробовал:

- При конфигурации добавлять флаг `-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON`.
- Нашёл, где лежат файлы `libav*`, добавлял путь к ним через `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.
- Сбилдил уже FFmpeg и тоже через `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/ffmpeg/lib` указывал путь.

Итог один:

```
Video I/O:
  DC1394:                      NO
  FFMPEG:                      NO
    avcodec:                   NO
    avformat:                  NO
    avutil:                    NO
    swscale:                   NO
    avresample:                NO
  GStreamer:                   NO
  v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
```

Подскажите, что ему нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: `-DWITH_FFMPEG=ON` должно работать... подразумевая что `cmake` сможет найти `ffmpeg`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а как он его не находит, если я ему через переменную показываю где лежит?

Comment: не смотрел, но скорей всего он через `pkg-config` ищет... чтобы конфигурировать с несистемным ffmpeg'ом нужно будет несколько переменных `cmake`'овских вручную задать... а для системного не забудь `-dev` пакеты ffmpeg'а поставить...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, забавно, но у меня нет таких =) apt не показывает и не устанавливает

Comment: в дебианах ЕМНИП они отдельные для каждой библиотеки libav: `libav{codec,format,utils,swscale,resample}-dev` и т.п. (c точностью до названий)